# Comparing two strings using memcmp in c

Tags: c

Consider the following code:

```
char str1[] = "Hello";
char str2[] = "Hello\0\0\0l\0o";
int x;
x=memcmp(str1,str2,sizeof(str2));
printf("%d",x);
```

When I run it, it shows the o/p as:

```
1
```

Can you explain the reason for this. I learned that each byte in both strings are compared and returns accordingly. But I am not clear about what happens at the end.

Comment: Are you sure `str1[]` and `str2[]` don't have any size?

Comment: Did you consider reading about memcmp in your beginner-level C book? Apart from the bug in your code, the answer to your question can be found there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your program invokes undefined behavior.

`sizeof(str2)` is larger than `sizeof(str1)`. By using that as the last argument to `memcmp`, you are accessing memory that you are not supposed to. That is cause for undefined behavior.

Hence, the output can be anything. It's pointless trying to make sense of it.

Answer (score 3):

when you do string compare, it will stop comparing once it reaches '\0'. In here you've done a memcmp, which will not stop until all the requested chars are read.

In this case you're comparing sizeof(str2) bytes, which in the case of str1 will give garbage after the implied '\0' at the end.

To get a 0 on the comparison:

- compare only sizeof(str1) or sizeof(str1)+1 bytes
- do a string compare

Answer (score 2):

Remember, it is **unsafe** and sometimes **danger** to call `memcmp` here because str1 has fewer length than str2.

Consider the following code:

```
int main()
{
    char str1[] = "Hello";
    char str2[] = "AAAAA\0\0\0l\0o";
    for(int i=0; i<sizeof(str2); i++)
        printf("%02X %02X\n", str1[i], str2[i]);
    printf("\n%X %X", (int)str1, (int)str2);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
48 41
65 41
6C 41
6C 41
6F 41
00 00
41 00
41 00
41 6C
41 00
41 6F
00 00

28FEEE 28FEF4
```

We can see the [6]-[11] bytes of `str1` is actually the first bytes of `str2`, and it could be confirmed by the address of `str1` and `str2`. In the case, GCC/MSVC (I'm not very sure about Clang) store the two string const initalizer in a row. So when you call `memcmp`, after the null-terminator `\0`, the function actually compares  the first byte of `str2` with `\0`.
But remember, the way compiler stores constant may change under any circumstance. You should **not** rely on this behavior.